# C# read byte pattern on large file

Tags: c#, file, design-patterns, byte

I'm new in C#, I want to count up a byte pattern inside of file. Everything is ok when I try to read a small file (8MB) and got 1907 in result, but when I try to read a large one (50MB) the app is freezing and return nothing. This is my code so far.

```
public long chunkMethodCW() 
{
    int incomingOffset = 0;
    byte[] outboundBuffer = new byte[1024];
    long CW = 0;
    KMP kmp = new KMP(header); // header = pattern in hex

    while(incomingOffset < data.Length)
    {
        int length = Math.Min(outboundBuffer.Length,data.Length - incomingOffset);

        Buffer.BlockCopy(data,incomingOffset,outboundBuffer,0,length);
        incomingOffset += length;

        //CW += kmp.match(outboundBuffer);
        CW++;
    }

    return CW;
}

// KMP Class 
public class KMP
{
    private int[] F;
    private byte[] pat;
    private int m;

    public KMP(byte[] pattern)
    {
        pat = pattern;
        m = pattern.Length;
        F = new int[m + 1];

        for (int i = 2, j; i <= m; i++)
        {
            j = F[i - 1];

            if (pattern[j] == pattern[i - 1])
            {
                F[i] = j + i;
                continue;
            }

            while(j > 0 && pat[j] != pat[i-1])
            {
                j = F[j];
            }

            F[i] = pat[j] != pat[i - 1] ? 0 : j + 1; 
        }
    }

    public int match(byte[] data)
    {
        int n = data.Length, pi = 0, ti = 0;
        int matches = 0;

        while (ti < n)
        {
            if (pi == m)
            {
                matches++;
                pi = 0;
                pi = F[pi];
            }

            if (data[ti] == pat[pi])
            {
                pi++;
                ti++;
            }

            else if (pi > 0)
            {
                pi = F[pi];
            }
            else
            {
                ti++;
            }
        }

        if (pi == m)
        {
            matches++;
            pi = 0;
            pi = F[pi];
        }

        return matches;
    }
}
```

I am still testing my code, and now I realize that my code is going freezing when its not meet the pattern at start, or there is a large gap between the start and when meet the pattern. Is there any suggestion to improve my code so it would not freezing when there is a large gap between start and first matched pattern. Thank you

Comment: So what do you expect people to do with this wall of code?

Comment: Is there any problem with my code or any suggestion to improve or totally change my method so it could be process a large file smoothly. Thankyou

Comment: suggestion: use more than 5 characters when naming your variables. it will make your code more readable

Comment: Is it the **reading** that is freezing, or the **rest of the code** that is freezing? Please narrow it down.

Comment: I don't know, maybe the rest of code, because when I start and then I leave it for a couple of hours it still freezing and result nothing

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the following information: What are your source and pattern byte array lengths? I tried and it didn't give me any freeze with a file of 63MB.

Oh btw I found a "bug" in your implementation. It is supposed to use some kind of a "window" of 1024 bytes long right? Basically the bytes gets copied to the window, the KMP applies the pattern match to the window, and the window slides to the read the next bytes. So if the cutoff is in the middle of a pattern, it will not return the correct number of pattern matches. I've corrected the code below, so the window slides less every time (to account for the possibly "cut" pattern):

```
public static long SearchBytePattern(byte[] source, byte[] patternToFind)
{
    int incomingOffset = 0;
    byte[] window = new byte[1024];
    long count = 0;
    KMP kmp = new KMP(patternToFind);

    while (incomingOffset < source.Length)
    {
        int length = Math.Min(window.Length, source.Length - incomingOffset);

        Buffer.BlockCopy(source, incomingOffset, window, 0, length);
        incomingOffset += length;

        count += kmp.match(window);

        if (incomingOffset >= source.Length)
            break;
        else
            incomingOffset -= patternToFind.Length - 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```